# How to connect Dell laptop to an external VGA monitor?

Tags: external-display

I have a problem with an external monitor.
The story so far: My laptop (Dell Latitude 7290) comes with a native highest resolution of 1366x768., which actually burns my eyes :)
That's why I decided to connect it to an external monitor (LG 24M38A - B). Turned out that my laptop has an HDMI port, but the monitor has only VGA (this 5-pin) port. So I bought a HDMI to VGA adapter.
It said "No input". The only way I could make it work is by lowering the resolution of the external monitor to 800x600 , which makes it practically unusable. All the drivers are updated. I am able to connect the monitor to another laptop (newer one, with a better resolution) without any problems.

Laptop:
Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8350U CPU @ 1.70GHz 1.90 GHz
GPU: Intel UHD Graphics 620.

I would appreciate any ideas and thank you!

Comment: It seems your HDMi-to-VGA adapter does not support resolutions higher than 800x600. Could you please tell us the brand and model name of your adapter? Then we can look into the manual to see which video modes are supported. A link to Amazon for example could also be fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely the HDMI-VGA adapter that has limited capabilities. Refer to [this Superuser thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1079278/can-an-hdmi-to-vga-adapter-have-a-resolution-limit) for more information.

Comment: Thank you! I cannot say what is the adapter - not a fancy one, for sure. But it says it is capable of 720p/1080i/1080p. And it works flawlessly with another laptop.

Comment: That info should be part of the question, not a separate comment. And since you wrote,  "it works flawlessly with another laptop," **state the resolution at which you find it works**.